# ERROR: Could not build wheels for bitarray, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, brownie

**Below it the error Its very lengthy so I have just copied the red portion of the error**

```
Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in 
c:\users\amazn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site- 
packages (from web3==5.23.1->eth-brownie) (306)
WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked 
version: 'protobuf' candidate (version 3.18.0 at  
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/9f3cb458266ef5cdeaa1e72a9 
0b9eda100e3d1803cbd7ec02f0846da83c3/
protobuf-3.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from 
https://pypi.org/simple/protobuf/))
Reason for being yanked: This version claims to support Python 2 
but does not
Building wheels for collected packages: bitarray, yarl
Building wheel for bitarray (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [11 lines of output]
  _bitarray.c
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(126): error C2106: '=': left operand must be 
l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(151): error C2106: '=': left operand must be 
l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(172): error C2106: '=': left operand must be 
l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(1429): warning C4996: 
'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords': deprecated in 3.9
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(1568): warning C4996: 
'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords': deprecated in 3.9
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(3273): error C2106: '=': left operand must 
be l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(3274): error C2106: '=': left operand must 
be l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(3275): error C2106: '=': left operand must 
be l-value
  bitarray/_bitarray.c(3276): error C2106: '=': left operand must 
be l-value
  error: command 
 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\
 MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin \\HostX86\\x6 
4\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a 
problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitarray
Running setup.py clean for bitarray
Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [56 lines of output]
  C:\Users\Amazn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env- 
 dhu3q3ml\overlay\Lib\site- 
 packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: 
 Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`     

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a 
 problem with pip.
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
       Failed to build bitarray yarl
 ERROR: Could not build wheels for bitarray, yarl, which is required 
 to install 
       pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I was trying to install brownie for my project however, I am unable to install it.
My "pip" is latest version.
and even my python.

can wnybody please help me? I am kinda new to this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not showing the full error, which would have more information why this fails.

Comment: It's very lengthy bro. The error happens when I try to install Brownie

Comment: [This Brownie package](https://pypi.org/project/Brownie/)?

Comment: @9769953 yes this one

Comment: Look carefully: that's from February 2011 (last update), and only supports Python 2. Installing the latest versions of Pip and Python is not very likely not going to work. You're better off finding another relevant package, or perhaps you don't need it at all.